# Алгоритм кластеризации на Python

Tags: python

Всем добрый день. Подскажите, как решить данную задачу на Python?

```
Нужно реализовать базовый алгоритм кластеризации, который также относится к области алгоритмов машинного обучения, 
то есть алгоритма k-Means. Описание данного алгоритма можно найти на сайте 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kmeans_clustering

Аспекты, которые будут оцениваться:
- Автономная реализация алгоритма с использованием базовых структур Python-list, Loop... и т. д.
- Реализация алгоритма с использованием готовой библиотеки Scikit-learn
- Реализация различных мер сходства множеств-Евклид, Манхэттен, Брей Кертис
- Реализация алгоритма классификации новых образцов на основе построенного классификатора
- Реализация графического пользовательского интерфейса с использованием библиотеки Qt
```

Как это реализовать? Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Начните с *Scikit-learn*

Comment: Я так понял, какие-то изверги вам категорически, под страхом смертной казни запретили самостоятельно пользоваться Гуугл. Придется вам помочь. Изучайте. Тут есть все ответы на все ваши вопросы.
Что неясно - спрашивайте, будем помогать отрезанным от благ цивилизации: https://machinelearningmastery.com/clustering-algorithms-with-python/ https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/08/comprehensive-guide-k-means-clustering/ https://towardsdatascience.com/k-means-practical-1ab126e52f58 https://towardsdatascience.com/k-means-clustering-8e1e64c1561c https://towardsdatascience.com/k-means-clustering-algo

Answer (score 0):

ой ну про первое два вот, кому надо)))

```
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score 
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Преобразование текста в TF-IDF признаки
vec = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vec.fit_transform(df_ready['Textl'])

# Уменьшение размерности текста с помощью PCA
pca = TruncatedSVD(n_components=2)
X_pca = pca.fit_transform(X)

# KMeans кластеризация
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
kmeans_clusters = kmeans.fit_predict(X_pca)

# Визуализация KMeans
plt.scatter(X_pca[:, 0], X_pca[:, 1], c=kmeans_clusters, cmap='viridis')
plt.title('KMeans Clustering')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

вот это кстати тоже рабочее

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
batch_size = 1007
dbscan = DBSCAN(eps=0.5, min_samples=5)
dbscan_clusters = np.zeros((len(X_pca),))
for i in range(0, len(X_pca), batch_size):
    start = i
    end = min(i + batch_size, len(X_pca))
    dbscan_clusters[start:end] = dbscan.fit_predict(X_pca[start:end])
dbscan_clusters = dbscan_clusters.astype(int)
# Визуализация DBSCAN
plt.scatter(X_pca[:, 0], X_pca[:, 1], c=dbscan_clusters, cmap='viridis')
plt.title('DBSCAN Clustering')
plt.show()
```

и вот

```
from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# MiniBatchKMeans кластеризация
n_clusters = 3
batch_size = 1000
mbkmeans = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters, batch_size=batch_size)
mbk_clusters = mbkmeans.fit_predict(X_pca)

# Визуализация MiniBatchKMeans
plt.scatter(X_pca[:, 0], X_pca[:, 1], c=mbk_clusters, cmap='viridis')
plt.title('MiniBatchKMeans Clustering')
plt.show()
```

Comment: if len(np.unique(dbscan_clusters)) > 1:
    silhouette_score = silhouette_score(X_pca, dbscan_clusters)
    print("Silhouette Score:", silhouette_score)
else:
    print("Недостаточно кластеров для вычисления метрики silhouette.")

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn.metrics import sil_samples   
# для каждой точки данных
sample_sil_val= silhouette_samples(X_pca, kmeans_clusters)
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
y_low= 10
for i in range(kmeans.n_clusters):
    ith_cluster_sil_values = sample_sil_val[kmeans_clusters == i]
    ith_cluster_sil_values.sort()
    size_cluster_i = ith_cluster_sil_values.shape[0]
    y_up = y_low + size_cluster_i
    color = plt.cm.viridis(float(i) / kmeans.n_clusters)
    plt.fill_betweenx(np.arange(y_low, y_up), 0, ith_cluster_sil_values,facecolor=color, edgecolor=color, alpha=0.7)
    plt.text(-0.05, y_low + 0.5 * size_cluster_i, str(i))  y_low = y_up + 10
plt.title('Sil plotting for KMeans')
plt.xlabel('Sil coef values')
plt.ylabel('Cluster label')
```

дополняю ответ

```
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score 
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Преобразование текста в TF-IDF признаки
vec = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vec.fit_transform(df_ready['Textl'])

# Уменьшение размерности текста с помощью PCA
pca = TruncatedSVD(n_components=2)
X_pca = pca.fit_transform(X)

# KMeans кластеризация
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
kmeans_clusters = kmeans.fit_predict(X_pca)

# Визуализация KMeans
plt.scatter(X_pca[:, 0], X_pca[:, 1], c=kmeans_clusters, cmap='viridis')
plt.title('KMeans Clustering')
plt.show()
```

Comment: лучше было дополнить ваш предыдущий ответ, нежели писать новый.